# Req ex for 9+2 Numerci plus decimal values

Tags: regex, req

I am looking for a regular expression with the following requirements:

1. 9 + 2 after decimal
2. If amount is zero, it should be invalid

I tried `^[1-9][0-9]*$` but it does work.

Comment: Have you tried anything? How didn’t it work?

Comment: I am trying by looking over blogs. For instance I just found ^[1-9][0-9]*$ for value greater than zero on stack flow site only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
^(?![0.]+$)\d{1,9}\.\d{2}$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/zo4DoM/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0.]+                    any character of: '0', '.' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{1,9}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 9 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead, anchored to start, for “zero”. Here’s one way:

```
^(?!0*\.00)\d+\.\d\d$
```

The subexpression `(?!0*\.00)` means “what follows must not be any number of `0`’s (including none) then `.00`".